# Git push is not working Error "You must use a personal access token or SSH key"

Tags: git, github, push, github-pages

Git is throwing error

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" push -u --recurse-submodules=check - 
-progress "origin" refs/heads/dev_civaplugin:refs/heads/dev_civaplugin
remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations.
remote: You must use a personal access token or SSH key.
remote: See https://github.build.ge.com/settings/tokens or 
https://github.build.ge.com/settings/ssh
fatal: unable to access 
'https://github.build.ge.com/108012572/NextGenUT.git/': The requested URL 
returned error: 403
Done

 Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

I cloned remote repository successfully using git extention and able to create new branch also but when tried to push my changes its throwing above error.

I created public and private key using Tools> putty> generate or import key 
my pc don’t have > .SSH folder in user
In git hub I created Personal access token also using Settings > Developer settings > Personal access tokens
Not getting clear idea of what the issue is, any input is a great help

Answer (score 47):

## Go to step #6 directly [follow from step #1 if you have single sign-on]

1. Generate an SSH key in your local machine (enter passphrase while creating key)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

2. Copy the public key which starts with `ssh-rsa`
3. Go to **Github > settings > SSH and GPG keys**
4. Click on `New SSH key` and paste the private that you've copied earlier, and create it

[image]

5. Now, enable SSO and authorize your org

[image]

6. Make sure that the newly created ssh private key is added into the SSH authentication agent

```
ssh-add <your-private-key>
(e.g., ssh-add id_rsa)
```

**Note:** By default, it will have your `id_rsa` primary key only; so, you need to add your custom private key in it.

Comment: **Correction to Step 2:** Copy the **public** key (**NOT** private) which starts with `ssh-rsa`. The public key file should end in `.pub`; the private key should lack any `.pub` file ending and its contents should clearly show `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`. DO NOT EVER give your private key to 3rd parties such as Github. -- Also, since you should only be pasting your **public** key, you don't have to blur out the summary info about that public key as long as your private key isn't compromised.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial, and successfully added my private key to GitHub.

But when using:

`git push https://<GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN>@github.com/<GITHUB_USERNAME>/<REPOSITORY_NAME>.git`

My password is still demanded, and the prompt ask for a token identification.

`remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.`

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 14):

See your `git remote show origin` — you have URL for the remote `origin` as `https://github.build.ge.com/108012572/NextGenUT.git/`. HTTP(S) protocol certainly doesn't use SSH keys, for SSH keys you have to change the URL to use `ssh://` protocol. Or you have to pass your Github name in the HTTP(S) URL. So either

```
git remote set-url origin https://user@github.build.ge.com/108012572/NextGenUT.git
```

to use Github token or

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://user@github.build.ge.com/108012572/NextGenUT.git
```

to use SSH keys.

Comment: "HTTP(S) protocol certainly doesn't use SSH keys" Thanks, that's the bit I was missing

Comment: For me the only syntax that worked was (using your example):

`git remote set-url origin git@github.build.ge.com:108012572/NextGenUT.git`

Comment: @Chaarmann `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.build.ge.com/108012572/NextGenUT.git` should also work.

Comment: Ya. For me also only worked without the 'ssh://' part. Not sure why.