# git clone not working with error " To access this repository, you must use the HTTPS remote with a personal access token or SSH with an SSH key"

Tags: git, ssh

Git is throwing below error when trying to run the command

```sh
git clone <<clone url>>:
remote: this repository, you must use the HTTPS remote with a personal access token
remote: or SSH with an SSH key and passphrase
remote: that has been authorized for this organization. Visit
remote: https://docs.github.com/articles/authenticating-to-a-github-organization-with-saml-single-sign-on/ for more information. The requested URL returned error: 403
```

As mentioned in the error I went through the url- https://docs.github.com/articles/authenticating-to-a-github-organization-with-saml-single-sign-on/, and followed the steps to configure SSL authorization.

In addition, I followed the steps for generating new SSH key and storing in SSH agent following this url: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent.

[image]

Also, I have configured the personal access token. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Still, I am getting the same error as above.

Please let me know if further information is needed.

Comment: Are you cloning using an SSH URL or an HTTPS URL?

Comment: Please post the results of: `git remote -v`

Comment: I am cloning HTTPS URL. I found somewhere suggestions to use SSH URL, but that didn't work.

Comment: @JoeCasadonte this is the result- fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git. This can be because, no project is getting downloaded as posted in the question.

Comment: How are you using the personal access token?  It should be able to work...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check that, for your SSH key, you have ([as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60146283/6309)):

- enable SSO
- authorize your organization

Then try again, using an SSH URL

```
git clone git@github.com:<organization>/<repo>
```

Comment: I did the steps mentioned in the link before, but was trying to download the project using HTTPS URL. Now, when I did it using the url as you mentioned, which is the SSH URL, it is working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You have to regenerate your ssh key with passphrase